# How can I find the current for a nonlinear electrical circuit using the Shockley equation, in Octave?

Tags: matlab, nonlinear-equations, iterative-method, octave

For this electrical circuit:

[image]

The voltage $ V_D $ can be found by solving a nonlinear equation:

$$ \frac{V_{DD}}{R} - \frac{V_D}{R} - I_se^{V_D/V_T} = 0 $$

In this example, let $R=1000$, $V_T = 0.025$, and $I_s = 10^{-13}$.

I want to solve this equation using Octave in the range $0<V_D<20$ with a 0.01 step.
Thus far, I have found a way to use `fsolve` to solve it time with $V_{DD}=9$ using the following code:

```
function y=f(x)
y=(9/1000) - (x/1000) - ( (10^(-13))*exp(x/0.025) );
endfunction

x=fsolve("f",1)
```

This correctly yields the following:

```
x = 0.6316
```

I'm happy that `fsolve` works quickly to solve this equation. However, I can't figure out how to get Octave to solve this same nonlinear equation 20,000 times, for input voltage $V_{DD}$ that varies from 0 to 20 with a 0.01 step. I'm not sure if `fsolve` is the best, or if Octave has another iterative solver to work with.

How can I do this with Octave?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way is to create a lambda function at call time which lets you set "extra" arguments. You can then call this in a for loop and vary the extra argument.

````
function y=f(Vd,Vdd)
  y=(Vdd/1000)-(Vd/1000) - ((10^(-13))*exp(Vd/0.025));
endfunction


Vdd=linspace(0,20,20001)
sols = zeros(length(Vdd))
for i = 1:length(Vdd)
  sols(i) = fsolve(@(x) f(x,Vdd(i)), 1);
endfor
```
````

Comment: It is worth noting that the convergence of the individual solves will likely be much more stable and marginally faster if you set the initial guess for each `fsolve` call to be the previous entry in `sols`, assuming you are working in serial and that the difference between nearby voltages are small. This will ensure that your initial guess is close to the true solution.

Comment: True, doubly important because no analytical Jacobian is specified.